# gradle hangs with selenium in my test case while eclipse does not even with driver.quit

Tags: selenium, gradle

I have been poking around quite a bit trying to solve this.  This test case

https://github.com/deanhiller/webpieces/blob/master/webserver/projecttemplates/templateProject/TEMPLATEAPPNAME-prod/src/test/java/PACKAGE/WithSeleniumTest.java

hangs in gradle but not in eclipse.  Basically, clone the project and "./gradlew test" hangs.

I am going to research debug mode for unit tests but not sure that gets me very far from the posts I have been reading like

https://discuss.gradle.org/t/help-my-gradle-script-hangs-during-build-at-end-of-tests/7505/15

So I ran the specific test in debug mode

```
./gradlew -Dtest.single=WithSeleniumTest :webserver:projecttemplates:templateProject:TEMPLATEAPPNAME-prod:test --debujvm
```

And it definitely got all the way to class teardown calling driver.quit() but then just hung for some reason :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ouch....I was calling driver.quit() but actually had to call

```
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

and now it doesn't hang!!!!

ugh...why two method calls.

Comment: `driver.quit()` shall ensure you do that in one method ;)

Comment: ^ yep but I've seen some bugs where FF throws while exiting so watch out for that.

Comment: BTW, don't forget to come back and accept your answer.